# Anyway to type convert all elements in solidity array?

Tags: solidity

I have been trying Solidity lately.
While trying to create a public int array.

Test.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.12 <0.9.0;

contract Test {
    int[5] public array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}
```

The following error is thrown:

> TypeError: Type uint8[5] memory is not implicitly convertible to
> expected type int256[5] storage ref.
>
> --> first.sol:4:27:
>
> |
>
> 4 | int[5] public array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
>
> | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

So I tried with type conversion, like below:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.12 <0.9.0;

contract Test {
    int[5] public array = [int(1), int(2), int(3), int(4), int(5)];
}
```

Which works, but type converting every element doesn't seem conventional to me.
Is there any other way?

--------------------- Edit ------------------------------

In solidity, just type casting first element works.
So following solved the problem:

int[5] staticArray = [int(1), 2, 3, 4, 5];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the compiler.

A small enough number literal (such as 1 or 2 in your example) fits into the type for `uint8` (max value 255), so the compiler treats the literal as `uint8` type by default.

You need to workaround this by using the typecast function, just as shown in your question.

```
int[5] public array = [int(1), int(2), int(3), int(4), int(5)];
```

Hopefully it's fixed in a later Solidity version.